# Best way to program flow through a job loop

Tags: origen-sdk

I see that Origen supports passing jobs to the program command in [this video](http://origen-sdk.org/origen/videos/5-create-program-flow/).  What would be the preferred method to run the program command in a job loop (i.e. job == 'ws' then job == 'ft', etc.).

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The job is a runtime concept, not a compile/generate time concept, so it doesn't really make sense to run the program command (i.e. generate the program) against different settings of job.

Origen doesn't currently provide any mechanism to pass define-type arguments through to the program generator from the command line, though you could implement that in your app easily enough by [overriding the program command](http://origen-sdk.org/origen/guides/misc/commandsov/) - i.e. capture and store them somewhere in your app and then continue with the regular command.

The 'Origen-way' of doing things like this is to setup different target files with different variables set within them, then execute the program command for the different targets.

Comment: OK so if I wanted to dynamically create the targets and run them in a loop, how would you do that?  Straight to LSF or is there a way to execute N program commands against different targets when overriding the command, perhaps using target loops (http://origen-sdk.org/origen/guides/runtime/programming/#Target_Loops)

Comment: There's no specific support for dynamic target generation. To do this kind of thing I normally make a command called 'build' within my application and then from there implement the different build options I want. And yes, using target loops quite often within that.

Comment: can i pass in options to an existing target versus creating new targets?

Comment: Yes, though I seem to remember that they did not work fully, so your YMMV and some Origen updates may be required to fully enable that.

Comment: Sorry, meant to include the link to configurable targets - http://origen-sdk.org/origen/guides/runtime/programming/#Configurable_Targets